# How to add one image to many buttons in ios using for loops

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have 3 buttons on the interface and an image.  i wanted to make NSArray of these 3 button and assign them only 1 image.
but how can i do that.
can i use for loop to assign the image to button.

Comment: please add a small small of your code, and probably a sketch of the end goal vs what you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, which I'm not sure, you want to do something like this :

```
NSArray * buttons = @[button1, button2, button3];
for (UIButton * button in buttons) {
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

If I didn't understand your question, do not hesitate to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks you are great,solved my problem of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an `IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray*` ([how to create `IBOutletCollection` arrays](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/28/interface-builder-outlet-collections.html)) property with all the buttons and assign the image using [`setImage:forState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage%3aforState%3a) method with the same `UIImage`:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myFile.png"];
for (UIButton* button in _buttons) {
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]
}
```